# Cannot render Vue-js in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to use Vue.js "stuff" inside of templates? I am trying to do this, but every time I try, nothing renders and a I get a worthless message in the console that says

> [Vue warn]: Error when rendering anonymous component:

Nothing gets rendered to the screen and there is no indication as to what Vue.js is having a problem with. Below is the code for the template:

```
   const list = {
        template: '<table><tr v-for="item in list"><td><router-link v-on:click.native="doSomething" v-bind:to="\'/item/\' + item.id">{{ item.title }}</router-link></td></tr></table>'
   }

   const viewItem = { 
        template: '<div>Not Implemented</div>'
   }     


   const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
          { path: '/item/:id', component: viewItem },
          { path: '/list', component: list }
        ]
    })

    const app = new Vue(
        {
            router: router,
            data: {
                list: [],
                test: "testing"
            },
            methods: { 
                 getList: //method to get data and populate list. This working correctly. 
                 doSomething: //method for fetching details.
            }
        }
```

Even doing something simple like {{ test }} in the template results in the same type of problem. If I use some static HTML, things work alright. If you can't do this inside of a template, how can you accomplish non-static HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may of course use Vue inside of templates.

The error you are receiving is because you incorrectly setting the `data` property. You have set `list` and `test` to the parent component, while you are trying to access them in your child `list` component. This produces an error while Vue tries to render the component, and thus the component is not rendered at all.

To fix just change your `list` component to the following:

```
const list = {
  data () {
    return {
      list: [],
      test: "Now you should see me :)"
    }
  },
  template: '<table><tr v-for="item in list"><td><router-link v-on:click.native="doSomething" v-bind:to="\'/item/\' + item.id">{{ item.title }}</router-link></td></tr></table>'
}
```

You will also need to move your methods to the component where you are using them.

Comment: Cool, I get it displaying {{ test }}. Do I need to move my getList() to this component as well?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. Each component will have its own methods section.